# Как называется состояние, когда ты знаешь, что так делать нельзя, но делаешь?

Tags: лексикография

Как называется состояние, когда ты знаешь, что так делать нельзя, но делаешь?

Answer (score 1):

Можно назвать такое состояние **смятением**, неким психическим расстройством, которому свойственны внутренние колебания, когда человеку кажется, что любой его выбор не имеет достаточно мотивации для окончательного решения в эту сторону: волнующий вопрос не даёт покоя, мысли спутываются, возникает состояние тревоги, появляются страхи, парализующие волю человека.

> На доске тем временем происходило смятение. Совершенно расстроенный
> король в белой мантии топтался на клетке, в отчаянии вздымая руки. [Михаил
> Булгаков. Мастер и Маргарита (1929-1940)]

Расстройство душевное также характеризует понятие **блуда**. Блудить (*лит*. blisti: темнеть; *рум*. blende: сойти с ума) — слабо видеть, блуждать в темноте; заводить не туда, куда надобно; заблуждаться, двигаться порочным путём.

> Виной ему вменялся блуд, влияние на царя и то, что он «церковь себе
> воздвеже без патриаршего благословения». [Андрей Вознесенский. На
> виртуальном ветру (1998)]

В церковной лексике **прелесть** имеет схожее значение искажённого состояния человека в оценке самого себя: прельщение, обман, заблуждение, соблазн, совращение от злого духа.

> Она бы пошла к невропатологу, к психиатру, а не к священнику, если бы в трещины расколотого сознания не проникало нечто постороннее, точнее, потустороннее, голоса и лица, всё нездешнее, тревожное, но иногда и невыразимо прекрасное… Прелесть? Обман? [Людмила Улицкая. Казус Кукоцкого [Путешествие в седьмую сторону света] // «Новый Мир», 2000]

Answer (score 0):

Неадекватное состояние.
Неадекватность - несоответствие, то есть, это состояние, при котором поведение человека не соответствует принятым нормам и моралям поведения. Такое состояние может быть вызвано либо излишней эмоцианальностью, перегрузкой психики, стрессовой ситуацией, психическими отклонениями(повышенный психоз, жизофрения), либо же при помощи воздействия некоторых веществ алкогольного или наркотического содержания.
P. C. Бывает, что неадекватные поступки совершаются во имя благой цели.  К примеру, производство заведомо преступных действий для предотвращения другого более серьёзного преступления.

Comment: А «Неадекватному состоянию» адекватное, не заимствованное слово найти можно?

Comment: В зависимости от контекста, можно. Например:" Находясь в невменяемом состоянии, он задавал нелепые вопросы."

Comment: Я про слово. Сочетанием слов объясняют. Словом называют.

Comment: "Неадекватность" в строгом смысле - несоответствие поведения _реальной_ ситуации, а не людским представлениям. Здесь могло бы подойти понятие "неконгруэнтность" (внутренний конфликт сознания с подсознанием, несоответствие поведения принципам, которые человек разделяет), соотв. здесь "неконгруэнтное состояние".

Answer (score 0):

Некоторые писатели (напр., Эдгар По и другие) упоминают "Дух Противоречия".Неплохо,из Русских, Брюсов (Валерий Яковлевич гг жизни 1873-1924) пишет в  "Республика Южного Креста" об этом. Называя это явление как болезнь  "mania contradicens".